# How to fix installation of 'ffprobe' on Mac Mojave

Tags: macos

I am using a Mac Mojave, and I have trouble using `ffprobe`. I get the following error:

```
$ ffprobe
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/x265/lib/libx265.179.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffprobe
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried to uninstall it which also did not work:

```
$ brew uninstall ffprobe
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ffprobe
```

I also run `brew doctor` which did not help.
I tried to install that tool but I got the output:

```
$ brew install ffprobe
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "ffprobe" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

So how to fix the issue with `ffprobe`?

Answer (score 9):

It seems that `ffprobe` is part of the `ffmpeg` package! I guess you need to know that (`brew` does not care to tell you that vital information!). So to fix this issue just reinstall `ffmpeg`:

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
brew install ffmpeg
```